# Debugging unicorn postgres connection leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-connection

Our new app had a lot of traffic yesterday and it started crashing. The error was PG max connections reached. This was very weird given our configuration -

PG `max_connections` = `100`
Unicorn workers = `8`
Sidekiq Processes = `1` 
Sidekiq Concurrency = `25`

So technically there should be only 34 active connections right? I dont think we have any multithreading in the app going on.

This was resolved once I restarted the db server and apps. Today, I am starting to see these connections popup.

Check the `pg_stats_activity`:

```
prod_db=# select datid, datname, pid, usesysid, usename, application_name, state from pg_stat_activity;                                                                             
 datid |        datname        |  pid  | usesysid | usename  |                        application_name                         | state  
-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 16384 | prod_db | 30104 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[1] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30094 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[0] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30110 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[2] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30116 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[3] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30123 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[4] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30129 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[5] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30135 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[6] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 30157 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[7] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 32161 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[5] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 32183 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[7] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 32273 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[5] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db | 32296 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[2] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db |   374 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[1] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db |   491 |       10 | postgres | sidekiq 3.4.2 app_production [0 of 25 busy]                     | idle
 16384 | prod_db |   498 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[7] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db |   581 |       10 | postgres | unicorn worker[3] -c /u/apps/e...ig/unicorn.rb -E deployment -D | idle
 16384 | prod_db |  1337 |       10 | postgres | psql                                                            | active
(17 rows)
```

Its weird that I am seeing multiple connections attributed to single unicorn worker processes.

Am I reading this correct? My hypothesis is that, this is the building block to the fatal event of postgres connections running out when there is a major load.

If that is true, how can one debug this? Any pointers? Thanks! :)

Would love to share more details if needed.

**postgresql.conf**

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.4-main.pid'
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_ident.conf'
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
log_line_prefix = '%t '
max_connections = 100
port = 5432
shared_buffers = '24MB'
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

**unicorn.rb** - https://gist.github.com/steverob/b83e41bb49d78f9aa32f79136df5af5f

**database.yml** -

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: app_name
  pool: 40
  timeout: 5000
  database: app_production
  encoding: utf8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, any thread in the application, when it executes a query in the DB (i.e. when it uses `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` in any way), it will get a connection to the DB, **separate from other threads**. The [`ConnectionPool` class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb) takes care of allocating DB connections to threads in Rails. Please read the class documentation for more info.

The pool can be up to `pool` (the configuration option in the `database.yml`) big. Thus, if you set the `pool` option to 40, each *process* (unicorn worker) may open up to 40 connections if it used 40 (or more) *threads*, so **in your case, unicorn alone may eat up to 40 * 8 = 200 connections**.

So, overall I think you must have some threading somewhere in your app (perhaps in a gem somewhere). If this is the same application as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497328/large-number-of-threads-under-unicorn?lq=1), then I'd guess it's definitely related to the multiple spawning threads.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue awhile back where unused connections were being left open. For me [PgBouncer](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer) fixed it

Comment: Thanks for that. I have also decided to use PgBouncer. But I wanted to find out why this is happening before installing this tool to solve the problem :)