# Large number of threads under unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, eventmachine, pubnub, keen-io

I am in the process of debugging some Posgtres connection leaks in our application. Few days back we suddenly crossed 100 connections when we should not be - coz we just have 8 unicorn workers and a sidekiq process (25 threads).

I was looking at htop today and saw that a ton of threads were being spawned from my unicorn workers. Eg:

[image]
Am I reading this correctly? This should not be happening right? If these are threads being spawned, any idea how to debug this?

Thanks! Btw, my other problem - (Postgres connections) [Debugging unicorn postgres connection leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484097/debugging-unicorn-postgres-connection-leak)

***EDIT***

I just followed some tips here - http://varaneckas.com/blog/ruby-tracing-threads-unicorn/ - and when I printed the stack trace from the workers' threads, here's what I got when there are many threads..

```
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `pop'
[17176] /u/apps/eventstream_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1057:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
[17176] ---
[17176] -------------------
```

This is my unicorn.rb https://gist.github.com/steverob/b83e41bb49d78f9aa32f79136df5af5f and it spawns a thread for EventMachine in after_fork.

The reason for EventMachine is this --> https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-gem#asynchronous-publishing

Is this normal? Shouldn't the threads be killed? Could this be also causing unncessary db connections to be open?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I just found out that I am using an older version of the PubNub gem which uses EM and I ran into these lines in the pubnub.log file -

```
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130123 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Created event Pubnub::Publish
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130144 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::SingleEvent#fire
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130162 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::SingleEvent#fire | Adding event to async_events
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130178 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::SingleEvent#fire | Starting railgun
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130194 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_event_machine | starting EM in new thread
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130243 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_event_machine | We aren't running on thin
D, [2016-04-06T21:31:12.130264 #1573] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_event_machine | EM already running
```

Comment: I also don't think that is normal. Maybe you are using `Thread`s in your application code? Could you try to use the procedure described [here](http://varaneckas.com/blog/ruby-tracing-threads-unicorn/) to get stack traces from the unicorn threads (see especially the _What Ruby is doing at any given moment?_ section)? This way you might find where the threads linger.

Comment: Wow. thanks for that link @BoraMa

Comment: I guess you have `reaper_frequency` configured in your `database.yml` so that middle thread is the [Reaper thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L300) and I think it's normal. We should wait till the threads accumulate...

Comment: @BoraMa Ahh ok ok. :) Updated with findings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after all, the behavior seems to be normal in your particular case.

The unicorn threads stack traces you provided (obtained using [this method](http://varaneckas.com/blog/ruby-tracing-threads-unicorn/)) point to [the `spawn_threadpool` method in EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/v1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1057). This code in EventMachine is called when some other code calls [`EventMachine.defer`](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/v1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1029), a method which **[spawns](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/v1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1051) a pool of 20 threads by default** on its first invocation. I found usage of `EventMachine.defer` in an older version of the `pubnub` gem (e.g. [here](https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/blob/eventmachine/lib/pubnub/client.rb#L79)) but it may as well be used from other places.

So, I think **this explains the high volume of threads** you observe on each worker. They mostly wait in the [`pop` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Queue.html#method-i-pop) which suspends the thread until something is pushed in the queue (deferred again in EventMachine). So unless you have a high load of deferred operations, the threads are mostly doing nothing.

If you don't need to have 20 threads on each unicorn worker ready for deferrable operations (most probably you don't), you can try to **lower the number of the threads in the pool by setting the [`threadpoolsize` variable](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/bc508be9862dfaddebe80612a4c439687684862d/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1106)** to some reasonable number, e.g.:

```
EventMachine.threadpool_size = 5
```

I would put this somewhere in the `after_fork` block in unicorn config.

Also, as another option, you might consider using the [unicorn-worker-killer
 gem](https://github.com/kzk/unicorn-worker-killer) to periodically kill unicorn's workers.

By the way, the messages that `pubnub` spits into its log seem to be OK, as it just tells us that it found an already initialized EventMachine threads so it does not have to start a new one. [This source code](https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/blob/eventmachine/lib/pubnub/client.rb#L295) clarifies it.

Comment: Awesome awesome!!!! I cant thank you enough for sharing so much stuff. :) :) If its not too impolite, is it possible for you check out my other issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484097/debugging-unicorn-postgres-connection-leak thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue today with version 4. When using PubNub in a background worker the thread count would continue to climb until we got an error.  The solution was as follows:

```
client = Pubnub.new(...)
client.publish(...)
client.telemetry.terminate
```